# Simple server status page hosted externally available for users

Tags: networking, php

I am looking for any kind of script - can be asp or php or any other web language - that gives me the ability to log outages and the current state of the network for our organisation.

This would be similar to any major Telco's "Network Status" page, but I just want to tell the user's out there if the systems are up and running and have a history of recent outages.

This would be for our remote user's so they could go to a webpage (externally hosted from our main site) and see that we are currently having problems with our network.

What are other people out there using?

Answer (score 1):

Nagios is a good tool for this.  You can host it on a web server and it has authenticated logins for security.

You might also try Spiceworks if you want something simpler.

Answer (score 1):

There are services dedicated to hosting system status pages such as [Status.io](https://status.io).

(Disclosure: I am the founder of Status.io)